# Why is 1 pod replica slower than other 5?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing

I have a multinode kubernetes cluster with 6 pods (replicas, 8Gi, 4 CPU cores)  running on different nodes residing in Auto Scaling Group. These pods contain an Application that serves REST API, and is connected to Redis.

For all the requests going through ALB configured via ingress, some requests are painfully slower than the others.

When I sent the requests at Pod-IP level, I found 1 pod to be much slower (almost 5 times as slow) than the other 5, bringing down the total response-time drastically.

I tried killing the pod, such that the deployment spinned up a new one which worked fine. The issue is, some other pod went slow because of this. The ratio of fast:slow is maintained at 5:1.

The CPU-utilization of the pods is below 30% and have ample available resources.

I am not able to figure out the reason. Please help.

Comment: If you look at the nodes on which the pods are deployed, is the slow pod deployed on a different host from the other pods? If so, is there anything unique about that host?

Comment: All the pods lie in the same VPC, and all nodes in the AWS cluster have similar attributes.

Comment: Did you find anything? We have same issue with 6 pods and a 6:1 ratio :)

Comment: Did you check memory consumption/allocation? Like memory requests/limits?

Comment: Have a look at CPU throttling metric of the pods instead of CPU-utilization.

Comment: On our end the affected pod gets throttled a lot more than the others although it gets the same requests / second with exactly the same request connected against the same database, but why does it use more CPU?

Comment: And why does the pod get throttled although it is not hitting 100% usage

Comment: Pod may get throttled when other pods on the same node use a lot of CPU, or if it hits the CPU limit set for the container. If you set CPU limits, look up how CPU throttling in kubernetes works, CFS quota, etc. Try reproducing the issue without the cpu limits.

Comment: We have found our issue, will answer tomorrow in depth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not the questioneer but oddly enough ran into a similar issue that could not be attributed to anything obvious per se.

After a lot of debugging and turning every stone we finally disabled the Prometheus Operator scraping our pods by removing the required annotation. The "1 pod performance issue" magically disappeared.

We kubectl forwarded one of the pods and checked our metrics endpoint: it was generating 6 MB (!) of metric data which is quite a lot and took around 700-1000ms to generate when no load is present. It turned out that a custom metric of ours had a regression and created a lot of tag-variants for a specific metric which attributed to nearly 3 MB of the generated metrics.
The next issue was Kafka Streams which generates a lot of very detailed metrics (even on a per Kafka Stream node operation basis or tagged in regards to every node in the connected Kafka cluster).
There is no easy way for us to disable the collection of these metrics but we just excluded them from our prometheus endpoint.

This left us with a meager 32kb of metrics. Reactivating the Prometheus Operator scraping did not re-introduce the observed issue.

But why one pod? We basically have two Prometheus Operator instances scraping all registered endpoints every 30 seconds which leads to an average scraping interval of  around 15 seconds.
We checked our http metrics and then it struck us: one pod is scraped 8-10x more often compared to any other pod! Considering a high load scenario its not unlikely that the prometheus endpoint exceeds 1.5 seconds to respond which would mean that another scraping process is started while the previous scrape is not completed yet.
All this was adding up more and more CPU usage leading to more throttling of the pod because it was hitting its CPU limit which in turn increased the metrics endpoints response time which lead to more concurrent scrapes generating 6 MB of data.

As to why one pod was scraped this often: we have no definite answer for this as of now as our systems team is still investigating. Sadly enough the 8-10x amount of scraping disappeared after we reduced our metrics endpoints response size.

We basically got DDOSd by metrics scraping which occured too often on one pod (reason unknown). This has to be the most complex thing I have ever debugged. We basically removed every part of our application (DB layer, tracing, prometheus, custom metrics) until we found the culprit. We even considered if specific Kubernetes nodes where the culprit and even checked if something like entropy was running out for whatever reason.

Good luck with your issue, I hope this helps some poor soul not waste more than a week of searching for a needle in a haystack!

Answer (score 0):

AWS ALB Ingress controller supports two traffic modes: `instance mode` and `ip mode`. Users can explicitly specify these traffic modes by declaring the `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type` annotation on the Ingress and the service definitions.

`instance` mode: Ingress traffic starts from the ALB and reaches the NodePort opened for your service. Traffic is then routed to the pods within the cluster. (default)

`ip` mode: Ingress traffic starts from the ALB and reaches the pods within the cluster directly. To use this mode, the networking plugin for the Kubernetes cluster must use a secondary IP address on ENI as pod IP, also known as the AWS CNI plugin for Kubernetes.

Default is `instance` mode.